# What i am doing wrong: Deserialize a JSON stream

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

```
    private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var mojetypy = await getWytypowane();
    }
```

it's my deserialize method:

```
    public async Task<List<WytypowaneMecze>> getWytypowane()
    {
        List<WytypowaneMecze> mojetypy;
        var serial = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<WytypowaneMecze>));
        var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("moje.json");

        mojetypy = (List<WytypowaneMecze>)serial.ReadObject(myStream);

        return mojetypy;

    }
```

when page is loading i get error :

**Exception:**
`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

**Additional information:** 
`[{"D_gosci":"Górnik Łęczna","D_gospodarzy":"Zawisza Bydgoszcz","Data":"13.02. 18:00","Wynik":"3-3"}]
[{"D_gosci":"Górnik Łęczna","D_gospodarzy":"Zawisza Bydgoszcz","Data":"13.02. 18:00","Wynik":"3-4"}]
[{"D_gosci":"Górnik Łęczna","D_gospodarzy":"Zawisza Bydgoszcz","Data":"13.02. 18:00","Wynik":"4-5"}]
[{"D_gosci":"Podbeskidzie B-B","D_gospodarzy":"GKS Bełchatów","Data":"14.02. 15:30","Wynik":"22-2"}]
[{"D_gosci":"Podbeskidzie B-B","D_gospodarzy":"GKS Bełchatów","Data":"14.02. 15:30","Wynik":"22-2"},{"D_gosci":"Wisła Kraków","D_gospodarzy":"Lechia Gdańsk","Data":"13.02. 20:30","Wynik":"44-2"}][{"D_gosci":"Wisła Kraków","D_gospodarzy":"Lechia Gdańsk","Data":"13.02. 20:30","Wynik":"1-1"}][{"D_gosci":"Wisła Kraków","D_gospodarzy":"Lechia Gdańsk","Data":"13.02. 20:30","Wynik":"1-1"},{"D_gosci":"Górnik Łęczna","D_gospodarzy":"Zawisza Bydgoszcz","Data":"13.02. 18:00","Wynik":"33-2"}]
[{"D_gosci":"Wisła Kraków","D_gospodarzy":"Lechia Gdańsk","Data":"13.02. 20:30","Wynik":"1-1"},{"D_gosci":"Górnik Łęczna","D_gospodarzy":...' is not a valid JSON primitive. This error can also occur when extraneous data is present after the JSON data.`

Comment: It helps to actually *read* your error messages: `is not a valid JSON primitive. This error can also occur when extraneous data is present after the JSON data`. Your JSON is probably malformed. Check it with a JSON validator.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is not valid. You are missing commas between the arrays:

```
...5"}][{"D...
```

should be:

```
...5"}],[{"D...
```

There may be other errors in the JSON too, but that is impossible to tell only from the snippet in the error message. You should check the JSON in a validator (like dandan78 suggested). You can use an online validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).